# Can I use this relay?

Tags: voltage, relay, amperage

I got [this](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07K796T9H/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) relay. 
In the product description they say: "belastet bis zu 10 Amp/250 VAC, 5 Amp 30 VDC." which means: "charged up to 10 amp / 250 VAC, 30 VDC 5 Amp".

On the relay it is printed: 10A/125V~

I would say that the description is not the same. Can I use it to switch on and off devices that are using 230V?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Always trust component markings before product descriptions, especially if you got the component from a dubious source (and yes, amazon counts as a dubious source in this context).

Comment: no, don't trust markings, check the data sheet, you might find that the markings specify a usage that gives a very short life.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe,

Sometimes the product markings don't cover all the device's capabilities. see if the manufacturer has provided more information in the datasheet.

Panaonic JS1 series relay datasheet:
https://www.alliedelec.com/m/d/eb12058a03bad44415c80ace65c84066.pdf

The data-sheet claims 277VAC capability, but this is excluded from the operating area graph on page 3.  perhaps contact Panasonic for guidance.